# Horizontal listview - lock selection to center item in screen

Tags: android, listview

I found out this tabbar widget on iOS:

[image: IDScrollableTabBar]

https://github.com/valitovaza/scrollableTabbar

How can I make a similar view for Android? Any suggestion please.

Comment: Please tell us what language / tool you are going to use and show us your code so far.

Answer (score -1):

There used to be GalleryView that has been deprecated since API 16 that could created a horizontal ListView. (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html)

I am pretty sure that RecyclerView could the same 
(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)

I hope this helps, happy coding! =P